# Dynamically populate the form based on the value previously selected by getting data from mongodb in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

So I am trying to build a online appointment hospital booking website using express and mongodb.
Based on the date selected by the user, the time slots that are available should be displayed from the database dynamically without redirecting.
I tried to get data nad using ajax request but I am not able to display data.
To be honest I don't like this method. If anybody could suggest a better method I would be very happy to adpot it.
booking_appointment.js

```
let date_selected = document.getElementById("date-selected")
document.getElementById("myCalendar").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios.post('/time_slots', {text: date_selected.value}).then(function (response) {
    console.log("Success");
  }).catch(function() {
    console.log("Please try again later.");
  })
})
```

app.js

```
app.get("/booking",function(req,res){
  res.render("book");
});  

app.post("/booking",function(req,res){
//req.body.text will give the selected date value.Based on this value time slots should be displayed from DB. 
  console.log(req.body.text);
});

app.post("/time_slots",function(req,res){
  let date=req.body.text;
  items=Slots.find_by(date: date).then((slots,err)=>{
    res.render("book",{slots:slots});
  }).catch(err=>   req.flash('error',"Something went wrong!Try again!"))
});

app.post("/booking",function(req,res){
  console.log("hurray");
  res.render("home");
});
```

book.ejs

```
<form action="/booking" method="post" >
<Assume there is a calendar here from which we will get date id='myCalendar'>
<p><%= (typeof slots != "undefined" ? slots : "okay i need to figure it out") %></p>
</form>
```

Can u please tell me how to populate time slots dynamically, thanks in advance.

Comment: @jfriend00 could you please help me sir?

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
app.post("/time_slots",function(req,res){
  let date=req.body.text;
  items=User.find().then((slots,err)=>{
    let data=JSON.stringify(slots);
   return res.json({slots: data})
  }).catch(err=>   req.flash('error',"Something went wrong!Try again!"))
});
```

booking_appointment.js

```
let Pname = document.getElementById("Pname")
document.getElementById("myCalendar").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   //wwe dont the default action to performed after submitting the form. we want to send an asnychoronous request to server 
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(e);

  axios.post('/time_slots', {text: Pname.value}).then(function (response) {
    // Create the HTML for a new item
    var $section = $('<div class="col-md-4"></div>');
  (JSON.parse(response.data.slots)).forEach(function(slot) {
    $section.append(`<h1>${slot.name}</h1>`);
  });
  $('#myCalendar').html($section);
    }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log("Please try again later.");
  })
})
```

book.ejs

```
<form action="/booking" method="post" >
<Assume there is a calendar here from which we will get date id='myCalendar'>
</form> 
<div id="myCalendar" class="vanilla-calendar"></div>
```